# "address in use" in trying to create child process

Tags: python, multiprocessing, zeromq

I am writing server on python using ZMQ and I want to draw plot in separate process, but after `process.start()` I get an error `"ZMQERRor:Address in use"`. How could I fix it? Why child process tries to connect to the same address, though it doesn't contain anything related to connection?

```
import zmq
import multiprocessing as mp

class Server:
    def __init__(self,host,port):
        self.context = zmq.Context()
        self.sock = self.context.socket(zmq.REP)
        self.sock.bind('tcp://'+host+':'+str(port))
        print 'Listening port :',port
        #--child-process---- 
        vis = Visualiser()
        proc1 = mp.Process(target=vis.show)
        proc1.start()

class Visualiser:
    def show(self):
        print 'something'

srv = Server('127.0.0.1', 1111)
```

Comment: Please post some code that reproduces the issue if you'd like some help solving the problem.

Comment: What happens if you reboot?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Nothing changes

Comment: I'm not getting any errors on Fedora 20 x86_64 with python-2.7.5-11 and python-zmq-13.0.2-1.

Comment: The code you posted works for me without reproducing that error. Normally, when you get an error `Address already in use`, you simply need to kill your Python process and restart your script.